# Use Exposed Filter value in no result Global text

Tags: tokens, views

I'd like to use the value of the chosen Exposed Filter (=dropdownlist) in the Global text block when there is no result.

**In detail:**
Exposed filter (which is a taxonomy list) has 3 values of provinces:

- Province 1
- Province 2
- Province 3

When there is no result using a chosen value, there should be a message (= global text, I presume), saying "Sorry, there are no addresses found in **Province 2**".

Is this feasible in Drupal views?

Comment: I think there is an existing feature to achieve a "no result behaviour" that displays a similar message with this king of token. I'm doing research :p

Comment: Go to advanced section in view.You will able to see "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR". Add "Global: Text area" put you text wants to display in no results found case.

Comment: Thank you for your investigation, but I want to add the chosen exposed filter into the Global Text area within 'no result behavior'. Is that possible?

Comment: Mmmh I begin to think that you have to do this programmatically to use the $_GET values sent by the exposed filters form... I didn't found any token for that.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a programmer... I have no clue how to develop this.

Answer (score 0):

1. set no result text area of view from advanced "No result behavior"
2. then edit your view using hook views_pre_render

Access your exposed input in same hook using :

```
$view->exposed_input['your field name']
```

then in same hook set these fields:

```
$view->empty['area']->options['content'] = "Set your message"; ( append exposed filter here)
$view->empty['area']->options['label'] = "Set your label"
```